# Symfony 4 - How to access variable from Controller to FormType

Tags: forms, symfony, variables, controller

I have in my ListProductsController  variable $parentId.
I want to get $parentId value and to use it in my SearchProductType:

```
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('price',EntityType::class,[
            'class'=>Product::class,
            'choice_label'=>'price',
            'choice_value'=>'price',
            'placeholder'=>'Default',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er){
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('product')
                    ->innerJoin('product.category','c')
                    ->addSelect('c')
                    ->innerJoin('product.manorwomen','m')
                    ->addSelect('m')
                    ->where('c.parent_id=1')

            },
            'expanded'=>false,
            'multiple'=>false
        ])
        ->add('submit',SubmitType::class)
    ;
}
```

c.parent_id must be equal to $parentId from controller

```
->where('c.parent_id=$parentId')
```

How to do that?

Comment: Please, remove “[SOLVED]” from title: accepting an answer is the way to mark it as solved.

Comment: Done,thank you for the help!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pass it as a required (mandatory) option to your `SearchProductType` form

```
/**      
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setRequired([
        'parentId',
    ]);
}
```

Then pass it when creating the form in `ListProductsController`

```
$form = $this->createForm(SearchProductType::class, $objName,
  ['parentId' => $parentId], //or whatever the variable is called
);
```

Finally use it

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $parentId = $options['parentId'];
    $builder->add('price',EntityType::class,[
        [...]
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($parentId) {
                [...]
                ->where('c.parent_id=' . $parentId)

        },
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HI can you try like this

**controller**

```
$data = array("parentId" => $parentId));
$form = $this->createForm(new ExampleFormType($data), $objName);
```

**form**

```
class ExampleFormType extends AbstractType {
    public $data = array();
    public function __construct($data) {
         $this->data = $data;  // Now you can use this value while creating a form field for giving any validation.
    }
}
```

you can access parentId from **$data** array

Comment: I suppose they could try it but it won't work.  At least not since Symfony 2.7.  Things have changed in the last 5 years or so.